# Flywheel timing

Tags: engine, diesel, timing, flywheel

I pulled the flywheel off my 4 cylinder diesel without checking any timing marks, I've since learned I probably should have. It's in the shop being machined right now (for new clutch), but I'm struggling to think of what purpose timing marks could serve on a flywheel for a diesel that has a mechanical belt driven fuel pump. I had assumed so long as I can bolt it back on correctly there would be no issue, am I missing something?

edit: thanks guys, it's a mechanically injected  4d56 from an '87 pajero/montero. I've since found out that this engine has no sensors/pickups, etc related to the flywheel, so orientation is not important.

Comment: It is a common rail system?

Comment: Are there crank position sensors?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Without knowing what the engine belongs to (year/make/model), we are going to be hard pressed to tell you if there'd be an issue or not. Every engine is different (by make/model/year), therefore the needs of the engine will be different. Editing your questing with this information will go a long way so we can give you the correct information.